# Poll hangs in c

Tags: sockets, server, tcp, client

```
#define RETRY_TIMEOUT 2

while(1)
{
    read_size = SocketReceive(hSocket, recvBuf, sizeof(recvBuf),
                              rsHndl, RETRY_TIMEOUT);
}

int SocketReceive(int hSocket,uint8_t* Rsp,short RvcSize, EMHANDLE *rsHndl,
                                      unsigned short timeout)
{                                     
    struct pollfd fds[1];
    int rv = -1;

    fds[0].fd = hSocket;
    fds[0].events = POLLIN;

    if ((rv = poll(fds, 1, timeout * 1000) > 0))
    {
        if (fds[0].revents & POLLIN)
        {
            shortRetval = recv(hSocket, Rsp, RvcSize, 0);
        }
    }
}
```

This is the client code. When i test with 10 clients with my server(capable of handling 250 clients), this code was working fine without any issue. When I try to use 250 clients, poll hangs in client side. This is the simplified version of code

Comment: Please don't provide a simplified version unless it can clearly be used to reproduce the problem. A simple explanation here would be that no data are there and thus poll does not report any data to read. This means one would not only need this code fragment but the actual code where the problem happens and sufficient information of how to run the code so that the problem happens. See [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Do you have any reason to think the problem is in the client? It sounds like it's most likely an issue with your server, and you haven't shown us any server code.

Answer (score 0):

This statement:

```c
if ((rv = poll(fds, 1, timeout * 1000) > 0))
```

Needs to be this instead:

```c
if ((rv = poll(fds, 1, timeout * 1000)) > 0)
```

Note the position of the 2nd-to-last closing parenthesis. `>` has a higher precedence than `=`, so the original statement is parsed as if it were written as this, which is not what you want:

```c
if ((rv = (poll(fds, 1, timeout * 1000) > 0)))
```

---

Also, `SocketReceive()` is declared as returning an `int`, but there is no `return` statement in your implementation.

With that said, try something more like this:

```c
while(1)
{
    read_size = SocketReceive(hSocket, recvBuf, sizeof(recvBuf),
                              rsHndl, RETRY_TIMEOUT);
    if (read_size > 0)
    {
        // bytes received...
    }
    else if (read_size == 0)
    {
        // peer disconnected...
    }
    else if (errno == ETIMEDOUT)
    {
        // read timed out...
    }
    else
    {
        // error ...
    }
}

int SocketReceive(int hSocket, uint8_t* Rsp, short RvcSize, EMHANDLE *rsHndl,
                                      unsigned short timeout)
{                                     
    struct pollfd fds;
    fds.fd = hSocket;
    fds.events = POLLIN;

    int rv = poll(&fds, 1, timeout * 1000)
    if (rv > 0)
    {
        return recv(hSocket, Rsp, RvcSize, 0);
    }
    else if (rv == 0)
    {
        errno = ETIMEDOUT;
    }

    return -1;
}
```

Comment: I have done the changes as per your code. But poll still hangs with 250 clients.